# Can "collection" pertain to a single object?

Tags: meaning, nouns, word-usage

Can "collection" pertain to a single object? For example, is a library with a single volume a "library"? Suppose the curator aims at acquiring more works of the same type as the one it possesses - there is an intent at making adding more volumes to the 'library'. Can it still be billed as a library?

Comment: Sure, everything with a beginning has to start somewhere, right? If you're looking for a more technical answer, it depends on whether the *system* exists - e.g. catalogue, numbering scheme, borrowing facilities, etc. If these exist and you'd be comfortable calling it a library except that there's only one book on the shelf, it's still a library.

Comment: This is partly a way of looking at things - you can call a single shell your entire shell collection if you like - but the [definition of collection](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collection) (things, plural) matters in everyday language. Your shell "collection" might elicit a chuckle or a puzzled look.

Comment: Think of saying **a collection of....** I might say *"I have a large collection of stamps,"*  But if I had only one, I'd have to say *"I have a collection of stamp."*  That just sounds weird. Basically the issue is not that it's technically incorrect, but that it just seems inappropriate.
In mathematics or computer programming, a collection could have one element, or even no elements, but people don't think about real world objects that way..

Comment: It may sound weird.  But that's simply because it is weird.  If I collect all the books I own into a box that box holds a collection, even if it's only one book.  Being a collection isn't about the number.  It's about the fact that the act of collecting has happened and this is the result.  If I say, here's my collection of gold medals and offer you my empty hand I haven't lied. I've just found a clever way to say I don't have any.

Answer (score 1):

A collection cannot be made of only one object.

> Library: a ​building or a ​room that holds a ​collection. 
>   Collection: a group of objects of one type that have been gathered in a specific location (building, room, album...)

Comment: The library's collection of rare books is down to one after the other one got stolen.